# Connecting to AWS Redshift through R - Mac OSX

Tags: r, odbc, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use the RPostgresSQL package to connect to Amazon Redshift through R and directly query databases. I'm running into this problem:

```
> drv <- dbDriver("PostgresSQL")
Error in do.call(as.character(drvName), list(...)) : 
  could not find function "PostgresSQL"
```

I'm a very new Mac/Unix user so I'm pretty confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close but are misspelling the command name

```
> library('RPostgreSQL')
Loading required package: DBI
> drv <- dbDriver("PostgresSQL")
Error in do.call(as.character(drvName), list(...)) :
  could not find function "PostgresSQL"
> drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
> class(drv)
[1] "PostgreSQLDriver"
attr(,"package")
[1] "RPostgreSQL"
>
```

Comment: Haha thanks. That's embarrassing. Always had trouble counting the 's' in PostgresSQL and the lack of sleep isn't helping.